# Redirecting output toward a scipt Task with SSIS

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to redirect the rows I selected from a table into a task script ?
I could do it all by code but SSIS is actually a lot more faster than this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found it.
In fact in SSIS 2008 there is the script component that you can find in Data Flow section.